# Conditionally change color of angularjs table tr td?

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angularJs, I need to change table inside some categories td color, Please help me!

Comment: Provide a [mcve] if you want someone to help you.

Comment: Use either the [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive or the [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i only resolved this issue

ng-class="(vm.filteredRiskScoreHeaderArray[$index].riskCategoryName!=null) ? \'riskcatclass\' : \' \' "

Answer (score 0):

ng-class="(vm.filteredRiskScoreHeaderArray[$index].riskCategoryName!=null) ? \'categorystyle\' : \' \' "

ng-class="(vm.filteredRiskScoreHeaderArray[$index].riskCategoryName!=null) ? \'categorystyle\' : \' \' "